# Simple C++ File stream

Tags: c++, file, stream

I want to read then store the content of a file in an array, but this isn't working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string content,line,fname;
    cout<<"Execute: ";
    cin>>fname;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<endl;
    //Doesn't work:
    ifstream myfile(fname);
    if(!myfile.is_open()){
        cout<<"Unable to open file"<<endl; 
    }else{
        while(!myfile.eof()){
            getline(myfile,line);
            //I don't know how to insert the line in the string
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, do you want to store each line into the std::string content or in an array? If so you can do content += line. If you want to store each line separately I advise you to use a std::vector instead of an array. It will save you the headache.

Comment: Doing this: 'while(!myfile.eof())' is generally wrong. See DanDan below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 things.
When creating your ifstream, you must pass a char*, but you're passing a string. To fix this, write :

```
ifstream myfile(fname.c_str());
```

Also, to add the line to the content, call the "append" method :

```
content.append(line);
```

It works for me :)

If you actually want to store each line seperatly, store every line into a string vector, like Skurmedel said.

Comment: The append method doesn't make the line break :(

Comment: Oh well. I didn't test the code with more than one line in the file, my bad ;)

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
while(!myfile.eof()){
        getline(myfile,line);
}
```

with

```
   char c;    
   while(myfile.get(c))
   {
        line.push_back(c);
   }
```

Comment: Although reading the file char by char is not great, you seem to be the only one who knows how (not) to use `eof` correctly. +1

Answer (score 2):

So you're trying to read the contents of a file into one string, or you want each line to be an array entry?

If the former, after you call `getline()` you will need to append the line (`+=` is a shortcut for append) `content += line;`.

If the latter, create a vector of strings and call `content.push_back(line)`.

Strings have a .c_str() method which returns a char array, so you probably need to call `ifstream myfile(fname.c_str())`.